# Fields in R.java Android library project are not final in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-library

The generated R.java in a Android library module looks like this:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static int trele_le=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static int line_lay=0x7f050000;
        public static int foo_bar=0x7f050001;
    }
    ...
}
```

Because of that it is not possible to use RoboGuice: @InjectView(R.id.line_lay) as it requires a final field as parameter

However in a non-library module, the fields ARE final.

How to attack this problem (make fields final?) ?

Comment: which version of ADT do you have?

Comment: 4.0. Changing to 4.0.3 did not help.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78599

Comment: Actually it seems ADT (Eclipse) has the same behaviour, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't. It merges the R files from dependencies into one R and uses it instead of former R files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it is a IDEA bug: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78599

Edit: Or not a bug after all, but rather intended design in Android SDK: http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields